# Are these Smith Normal Forms correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the Smith normal form of these matrices correct?

A = $\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 3 & 0\\ 
-3 & 3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 6 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

B =$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
3 &  4\\ 
2 & -4
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 10\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: These sorts of yes/no questions don't make good questions for math.stackexchange.com. It would be better to learn how to use Sage or Mathematica to double check your calculations. For example go to https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ and type in `matrix([[-3,3,0],[-3,3,6]]).smith_form()` and hit evaluate.

Comment: To be clear: yes/no questions are fine if you can't find the answer anywhere else. But questions where I just plug it into my computer would be better if you learned how to plug it into your computer yourself.

Comment: I tried using MATLAB but SmithForm only works for square matrices, couldn't find anywhere else.

Comment: You can get around that by padding your matrix with 0s I believe. I've never used MATLAB myself but I've always associated it with numerical computation and anything more symbolic with Sage, Maple, Mathematica. Integer matrices I consider more on the symbolic side because the solution is exact rather than correct to so many digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those are the correct forms. You can compute SNF in Sage using the following commands.

```
matrix([[-3,3,0],[-3,3,6]]).smith_form()
matrix([[1,-2],[3,4],[2,-4]]).smith_form()
```

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/